# Dúvida sobre modelagem do front end baseado nos dados

Tags: front-end

estou com muitas dúvidas para modelar dados do tipo *Cargos*. Ex:

```
funcionario------cargo = 1
chefia-----------cargo = 2
chefia da chefia-cargo = 3
big boss---------cargo = 4
```

Nesse caso, seria interessante eu criar uma tela que apareceria todas as opções independente do seu nível de cargo, e quando você quiser entrar em um lugar restrito eu perguntaria se você tem o devido cargo e não deixaria você passar ou criaria uma tela para cada cargo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As duas abordagens são válidas. A escolha depende de alguns fatores:

Similaridade - o quanto as telas de cada cargo são similares ou não. Desta forma, pode fazer sentido até misturar as duas abordagens. Por exemplo, você pode decidir que as telas do funcionário e do big boss são muito diferentes e cada um ter a sua tela, já as dos chefes são mais parecidas e uma unica tela, com pequenas diferenças resolve.

Complexidade - No lado oposto do item anterior, qual a complexidade de cada tela? Que fontes de dados ela tem que carregar? Quais as diferenças entre cada ator?

Escala - E amanhã? Quanto pode crescer este sistema? Quem vai dar manutenção?

Uso - Cada usuário vai ter acesso a um computador ou eles tem de partilhar o mesmo?

Estrutura - Depende do estilo do desenvolvedor. Alguns preferem poucos arquivos com muita funcionalidade embutida, enquanto outros preferem pulverizar o código em diversos arquivos menores.

Todos estes detalhes devem ser pesados na escolha de sua abordagem.

Outra questão que você levanta é a identificação do cargo. Presume-se que sendo um sistema empresarial, o usuário se identifica ao iniciar o uso do computador (login) e nesta hora, você já direcionaria a tela para este sujeito.

Do contrário, isto é, uso sem identificação, você não tem escolha a não ser mostrar todas as opções e restringir o acesso de acordo com o caso.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que você poderia adequar a tela de acordo com seu devido cargo, mas isso não precisaria ficar amostra para o usuário, por exemplo:

```
user 1 cargo 1 ---- vai acessar a tela perfil(ex.) > adiciona elementos genericos
user 1 cargo 2 ---- vai acessar a tela perfil(ex.) > genericos + (elemento relacionado ao cargo)
user 3 cargo 1 ---- vai acessar a tela perfil(ex.) > generico
```

mas ai você verifica pela busca de resultados de alguma API e adiciona os elementos, na forma de `single page application`.